# Is it possible to identify what machine made a Windows Backup?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-backup

I handle some network administration for a small business. Recently, I discovered a set of windows backup files in a directory that was being regularly added to (multiple times daily) on our backup server. After speaking to my supervisor, he has no idea where it comes from either. Naturally, we'd like to figure out where these files are coming from.

**What information can be identified from a windows backup file without restoring the file? How is this information retrieved?**

*Note: This questions is directly related to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/962645/how-do-i-log-file-writes-to-a-directory-on-windows-server-2003), hence the identical question description/background.*