# How do I log file writes to a directory on Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-backup, event-log

I handle some network administration for a small business. Recently, I discovered a set of windows backup files in a directory that was being regularly added to (multiple times daily) on our backup server. After speaking to my supervisor, he has no idea where it comes from either. Naturally, we'd like to figure out where these files are coming from.

**How do I log file writes, using the Windows Event Logs, to a given directory on Windows Server 2003?** I would like to avoid using group policy here, as this is a temporary need.

*Note: This questions is directly related to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/962220/is-it-possible-to-identify-what-machine-made-a-windows-backup), hence the identical question description/background.*

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of in this situation is to look at the share itself. You can check the event viewer to view what account last accessed it (search for similar times to your files) which should narrow down what user is placing the files. If they set things up like I do it should be an automated service using a service account (AD) which should be able to "tell" you where/what it's coming from